# Storing Instances in a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What I wish to do is create multiple instances of class Enemy without having to create each one of them individually.

What is the best way to go about it, using an array or a vector?

///CODE IS HERE:

```
  void GameLoop(SDL_Window* Window, SDL_Renderer* Renderer)
  {
    //CREATE ENEMIES
    Enemy* Enemy_1 = new Enemy(Renderer, "S_Alien_1.bmp", 200, 100, 50, 35);
    Enemy* Enemy_2 = new Enemy(Renderer, "S_Alien_1.bmp", 260, 100, 50, 35);

    //CALL UPDATE FUNCTION OF ENEMY CLASS
    Enemy_1->Update();
    Enemy_2->Update();

    //CALL DRAW FUNCTION OF ENEMY CLASS
    Enemy_1->Draw();
    Enemy_2->Draw();

  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an array or a vector? What problems you run into?

Comment: The answer is, it depends. Use vector if the number of enemies can vary, or array of the number is static (like in pacman)

Comment: Your `Enemy` class has constructor parameters, and you are clearly passing different values for different instances, so you HAVE to create each instance individually. Whether you use a fixed array or a vector, that fact doesn't change. If you want to create multiple instances at one time, that is doable, but you will have to construct them all with default values first, then individually re-configure them as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way would be a vector for your game its best to define the enemy outside of a loop and then loop run the loop as many time as you want enemies

```
std::vector <Enemy*> eList;

Enemy* enemy;
for(int i =0; i < eCount;i++){
enemy = new Enemy(blah);
eList.push_back(enemy);
enemy = nullptr;
}
```

then anytime you want to access a instance function you can reference which it is in the for list or if you want to access all of them you can do a for each loop

```
for each(Enemy* e in eList){
    e->function;
}
```

Comment: You should NOT be using `new` here. This creates a memory leak and serves no purpose.

Comment: @super alright well what would you recommenced, don't just say whats wrong, correct me and tell me whats right

Comment: @NanoedStux - This method works and I now have multiple instances of the enemy on the screen and they are doing what they should be. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can `eList.push_back(Enemy(blah));` or even better use `eList.emplace_back(blah);` Using new allocates on the heap, and it needs to be `delete`ed later, and this is the very thing one usually wants to avoid when using a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Use vector fill constructor:

In place of 100 you can use any number.

```
std::vector<Enemy> enemies(100, Enemy(Renderer, "S_Alien_1.bmp", 200, 100, 50, 35));
```

Comment: Why is `new` involved here? Same as for the other answer it's not needed and should not be used when populating a vector.

Comment: What is the problem when object is deleted?

Comment: It's a problem in the sense that it's completely unnecessary. The reason to use a `std::vector` is normally to be able to dynamically allocate things without having to use `new` and `delete`. You are making a more costly operation by allocating an object on the heap for no reason and with no gain.

Comment: With that said, your second suggestion of using an `rvalue` has minimal overhead and is good practice in general.

Comment: How should the first one look than?

Comment: The first one should look like the second one. They do the exact same thing but the second one is more efficient and less prone to errors.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying